# Como compilar C/C++ para Linux/Mac OS em um Windows?

Tags: windows, cross-platform, gcc, mingw

O título diz tudo. Tenho código que pode ser compilado nas duas (três?) plataformas e desejo fazê-lo direto do Windows apenas usando o GCC (MinGW, no caso). Seria isso possível, em relação a *cross-compiling*? Como o faria no meu caso?

Comment: É possível sim. [GCC Cross Compiler](http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler).

Comment: @QMechanic73 atualizei a pergunta se quiser responder

Comment: @QMechanic73 foi exatamente dessa página que eu tirei a dúvida hahaha

Comment: Pode ser uma ajuda http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/porting/linux/

Answer (score 1):

Acho que o mais importante é fazer o teu projeto de uma forma que se possa compilar em diversas plataformas facilmente. Eu utilizo o [cmake](http://www.cmake.org) ([cmake cross compiling](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling)). Com o cmake, eu consigo compilar para Visual Studio, GCC, MingW (cross-compiler instalado no Linux), Clang (Mac e Linux), sem qualquer trauma, vale muito a pena.

O segundo passo é portar o seu código para atender adequadamente todas as plataformas, vamos assumir que você utiliza sockets, a resposta de um *connect timeout* dado pelo VC++ é erro 10060 com uma mensagem pré-definida, já no MingW não é possível recuperar a mensagem de erro. Sua aplicação deve prever essas nuanças das plataformas.

E você deve baixar o toolchain de Linux no Windows. Acho que baixando o [msys2](http://www.msys2.org) e instalando o cmake com um cross compiler de Linux, ficaria mamão com açucar compilar o seu projeto. Apesar que eu faço o oposto, desenvolvo na máquina Linux e compilo para target Windows, e a distribuição final numa VM com o VC++.

Por fim, se não tiver um toolchain em mão, você pode criar o seu. Basicamente, você tem que compilar o binutils no Windows para o target Linux, e depois compilar o gcc com o binutils que você acabou de compilar. Vou deixar a [referencia](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/install_tools.html) como criar um crosscompiler para arduino, eu utilizo esse método porque eu tenho sempre em mão o gcc mais novo, no caso do Arduino.